# For each matrix A and ordered basis β, find the $\beta$-to-$S$ change of coordinates matrix $P$ (where $S$ is the standard basis).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

For each matrix A and ordered basis β, find the $\beta$-to-$S$ change of coordinates matrix $P$ (where $S$ is the standard basis).

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3\\
1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$,

$\beta= \{\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\}$

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to find the change of coordinate matrix?
I know how to find the matrix for a basis $\beta$ or $S$, but I'm not sure how to find the $\beta$-to-$S$ change of coordinates matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The change of basis matrix is the matrix whose columns are the basis vectors: $P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

(It's its own inverse, so we get $PAP$ for the new matrix.)

The way I remember this is that, if you apply $P$ to the standard basis, which is, in fact, the basis $\beta$ expressed in terms of itself, you get the basis $\beta$, expressed in terms of the standard basis.